# Suppose $3_1+2_2−_3=_4$. Which of the following statements are true?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

$\newcommand{\span}{\text{span}}$

**Question: Suppose $3_1+2_2−_3=_4$. Which of the following statements are true? ​​​​​​**

- $\span( {_1,_2,_3} ) = \span( {_1,_2,_3,_4} )$
- $\span( {_1,_2,_4} ) = \span( {_1,_2,_3,_4} )$
- $\span( {_1,_2,_3} )$ is contained in but not equal to $\span( {_1,_2,_3,_4} ).$
- $\span( {_1,_2,_4} )$ is contained in but not equal to $\span( {_1,_2,_3,_4} ).$

**I chose answers **1 and 2**, but I am new to this topic so I am not entirely sure if it's correct.**

Does $_3$ qualify as a valid linear combination of all vectors: $$ _3 = 3_1 + 2_2 - _4 + 0_3$$ AND/OR  $$ _3 = 6_1 + 4_2 - 2_4 - _3$$

If yes, then 2nd statment is true right?
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is the first one since the non trivial containment is due to the fact that you find a $\textbf{non trivial}$ combination of $u_{4}$, expressed as linearly dependant from $u_{1},u_{2},u_{3}$.

Comment: The bold sentence answers to the second question too

Comment: Hi, which bold sentence were you referring to?

Comment: @user594831 The one I stated above. Try to recall the definition of linearly independenat or dependant.

Comment: Does this mean u4 = 3u1 + 2u2 - u3 + $0$u4 is an invalid linear combination? or u4 = 6u1 + 4u2 - 2u3 - u4 is an invalid linear combination?